# how to check input boxes according to values

Tags: jquery

Suppose, I have the follwoing html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="products" value="1" id="product_1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="products" value="2" id="product_2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="products" value="3" id="product_3" />
```

jquery:

```
var list = [1,2];
```

Now I'm stucked at how to check the checkbox if the value matched in list. In my example first and second input is to be checked on ready.

Comment: have you tried anything???

Comment: `$('#product_' + list.join(', #product_')).prop('checked', true);` -> http://jsfiddle.net/69S9x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the id selector, since the id contains the value

```
var list = [1, 2];
$.each(list, function (i, val) {
    $('#product_' + val).prop('checked', true)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wXkTZ/)

If you are doing a reset operation then

```
var list = [1, 2];
$('input[name="products"]').prop('checked', function () {
    return $.inArray(parseInt(this.value), list) > -1
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TL5sT/)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the array of values, then check each input based on the product ID.

```
list.forEach(function(item) {
    $('#product_'+ item).prop('checked', true);
});
```

A more advanced solution would be to build a selector, then check them all at once.

```
$( list.map(function(item) {
    return '#product_'+ item;
}).join(',') ).prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, You can use id attribute  `product_*` as selector

```
var list = [1,2];

$.each(list,function( index, value ) {
   // alert( index + ": " + value );
    $("#product_"+value).prop('checked', true);
});
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/JhBAP/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="1" id="product_1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="2" id="product_2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="3" id="product_3" />
```

Script

```
var list = [1, 2];
$("input[name='products[]']").each( function(i,j) {
if(jQuery.inArray(parseInt($(this).val()), list)!= -1){
$(j).attr('checked', 'checked'); //OR $(j).prop('checked', true);
}
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bsEez/)

Comment: The field names aren't `products[]`, but probably should be. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
$('[name=products][value=' + list.join('],[name=products][value=') + ']').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jquery.inarray](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/)

```
var list=[1,2];
    $('input[name=products]').each(function(){
                  if(jQuery.inArray(parseInt($(this).val()), list)!=-1)
           {
               $(this).prop('checked', true);
           }
    });
```

> [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uy2mb/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=products]').prop('checked', function() {
  return (list.indexOf(~~this.value) != -1);
});
```